# OS X: make pkg, post install script running as root

Tags: macos, pkgbuild, file-ownership

I'm using [Packages](http://s.sudre.free.fr/Software/Packages/about.html) to build PKG installer. Its goal quite simple: deliver my app to `/Applications` folder and launch it. Packages.app is doing its job almost well except one thing. When it launches post install script (simple script that launches just installed app), the script is launched as root, hence the app is launched as root too. This is undesired behaviour. It's strange why the installer requires Admin password during installation, I keep this setting unchecked in PKG project. So, the question is: how to make installer run post install scripts under current logged user?